# Python - move and read .txt files from Windows folder to Linux server

Tags: python

I'd need to read and move some .txt files from a windows server (eg. 192.168.xxx.xxx\Share) to a folder in my Linux server where the script should run in crontab.

Is there a smart way to do it? I'm thinking something like below

```
    import paramiko


def move_txt_file_task():
    try:
        ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='192.168.xxx.xxx',username='xxx',password='xxx')

        ftp_client=ssh.open_sftp()
        ftp_client.put('/root/giles/test','\\192.168.xxx.xxx\Doc-Share\Log')
        ftp_client.close()

    except paramiko.SSHException:
        logging.info("Invalid Username/Password")
```

But I get this error:

```
> paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: What type of protocol is the remote server using? FTP, SSH, Windows Share?

Comment: use any ssh client (putty,windows builtin ssh) in order to connect to the machine. Are you able to connect?

Comment: Yes I am, the machine is in my same network, I'm able to connect with every ssh method

Answer (score 1):

Use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) in order to transfer file to the linux machine.

See more [here](https://medium.com/@keagileageek/paramiko-how-to-ssh-and-file-transfers-with-python-75766179de73).

```
ftp_client=ssh.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put(‘localfilepath’,remotefilepath’)
ftp_client.close()
```

Comment: and what is the result ?

Comment: I tried something like this:

import paramiko


def move_txt_file_task():
    try:
        ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname='192.168.xx.xx',username='xx',password='xx')

        ftp_client=ssh.open_sftp()
        ftp_client.put('/root/test/files','\\192.168.xx.xx\Share\foldert')
        ftp_client.close()

    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print(f"Invalid Username/Password")

Comment: please share the code using your question as well as the issues you are facing.